# Hosting Jekyll website with Amazon S3 + Cloudfront with private registrar (namecheap), issue with blog posts not showing up on blog page

Tags: amazon-s3, jekyll, amazon-cloudfront, jekyll-theme

Sorry for the wordy title.

Basically I created a jekyll website using Jekyll Now theme, it worked perfectly as as static site, here is the github version: fitnessregiment.github.io which is how I want the site to look. If you go to Blog you can see 1 blog post /essential-softwares-for-windows/.

Now the issue is that once I enabled cloudfront in order to enable HTTPS on my main domain: [alexis-drakopoulos.com](http://alexis-drakopoulos.com) a few things went wrong, I managed to fix some but one of the main ones I cannot fix is the blog posts do not show up on the blog page. They do however exist as seen at https://alexis-drakopoulos.com/essential-softwares-for-windows/

So to explain how the site works:
Github repo: github.com/FitnessRegiment/fitnessregiment.github.io/

Then gets managed through forestry.io CMS which uploads straight to amazon S3.

Amazon S3 bucket endpoint: alexis-drakopoulos.com.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com

Cloudfront URL: d2cmpfzgichbat.cloudfront.net (which as you can see does not show blog posts).

So I cannot figure out what could be going wrong, cloudfront not understanding the structure? I'm not sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it's still serving an older version of the page. You need to trigger a CloudFront cache invalidation. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html

Comment: Okay stupid question but, I disabled IPv6 and went to bed, woke up and it was working. So either its a coincidence and the site just started serving new page, or the IPv6 was causing the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: The cache automatically expires after a while. It has nothing to do with the IPv6 settings.